# BadUSB with atmega328P instead of 32U4? Is it possible?

Tags: arduino

Where I live I can’t really get my hands on an arduino pro micro without waiting an extensive amount of time for the delivery. Can I by any chance use an arduino nano for the job without having to buy a seperate usb compatibility chip?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

The nano and uses the 328p, not 32u4.
The 32u4 makes it easier to make USB/MIDI devices though.
(It's possible to achieve this with a 328p as well, just not as trivial)

Pick the board that makes most sense in terms of your project requirements.

You won't have to buy a separate chip for USB/Serial conversion,
you'll need a mini USB for the Nano instead of micro USB cable (used for the Pro Micro)

Comment: [Pro Micro](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12640) uses an ATmega32U4. You are probably mixing it up with [Pro Mini](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-pro-mini) which uses an ATmega328P or Atmega168.

Comment: @gre_gor true, oversight on my side, thank you for pointing that out

Comment: And if you use a Nano, you can't use the existing USB connector.

Comment: @gre_gor I doesn't the Nano have a miniUSB connector ?

Comment: It's connected to the FTDI chip. And you can't make it do HID or have the ATmega328P have any control over USB besides sending serial data.

Comment: @gre_gor I remember bumping into a few projects like [LUFA](http://smartinteractionlab.com/lufa-example-turning-your-arduino-into-a-keyboard/), [V-USB](http://vusb.wikidot.com/driver-api), [etc.](http://code.rancidbacon.com/ProjectLogArduinoUSB), but as mentioned, not straight forward on 328p